# graphene-django v2.0 depth validation

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-django

Is there any way I can validate the query depth with `graphene-django` 2.0?
I've tried to use this suggested [backend](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/907#issuecomment-498679759):

```py
from graphql.backend.core import GraphQLCoreBackend

def measure_depth(selection_set, level=1):
    max_depth = level
    for field in selection_set.selections:
        if field.selection_set:
            new_depth = measure_depth(field.selection_set, level=level + 1)
            if new_depth > max_depth:
                max_depth = new_depth
    return max_depth

class DepthAnalysisBackend(GraphQLCoreBackend):
    def document_from_string(self, schema, document_string):
        document = super().document_from_string(schema, document_string)
        ast = document.document_ast
        for definition in ast.definitions:
            # We are only interested in queries
            if definition.operation != 'query':
                continue

            depth = measure_depth(definition.selection_set)
            if depth > 3: # set your depth max here
                raise Exception('Query is too complex')

        return document

    url(r'^api', csrf_exempt(FileUploadGraphQLView.as_view(
        schema=schema, middleware=(middleware), backend=DepthAnalysisBackend()))),
```

but it returns the error `FileUploadGraphQLView() received an invalid keyword 'backend'. as_view only accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class.`

Comment: your django version?

Comment: @Devstorm21 1.11.14

Answer (score 0):

You can set the schema, the middlewares and the backend in your settings file.

Like this:

```
GRAPHENE = {
"SCHEMA": "the.path.to.your.schema",
"BACKENDS": ["the.path.to.your.backend",],
'MIDDLEWARE': ['the.path.to.your.middleware',],}
```

And leave the url like this:

```
url(r'^api', csrf_exempt(FileUploadGraphQLView.as_view()))
```